# React Native Create Components with multiple condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, lodash

I have a data structure like this:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const bills = [
  {year:2021, month:5, bill:'bill in 2021 may'},
  {year:2018, month:1, bill:'bill in 2018 jan'},
  {year:2019, month:1, bill:'bill in 2019 jan'},
  {year:2018, month:2, bill:'bill in 2018 feb'},
  {year:2019, month:10,bill:'bill in 2019 oct'},
  {year:2019, month:2, bill:'bill in 2019 feb'},
  {year:2019, month:6, bill:'bill in 2019 jun'},
  {year:2020, month:11,bill:'bill in 2020 nov'}
];
```

and I want to display like below using Text or Card component of native-base

```
2018
  1
    bill in 2018 jan
  2
    bill in 2018 feb
2019
  1
    bill in 2019 jan
  2
    bill in 2019 feb
  6
    bill in 2019 jun
  10
    bill in 2019 oct
2020
  11
    bill in 2020 nov
2021
  5
    bill in 2021 may
```

My codes are below using lodash library to generate above and display in the terminal

```
// sort the data first
let arrSortedTasks = _.orderBy(tasks, ['year', 'month'],['asc']);
// get all the different year from the data
let arrUniqYear = _.uniqBy(arrSortedTasks, 'year');
// get all the different month from the data
let arrUniqMonth = _.uniqBy(arrSortedTasks, 'month');
// take out only the value of the year
arrUniqYear =_.map(arrUniqYear, 'year');
// take out only the value of the month
arrUniqMonth =_.map(arrUniqMonth, 'month');

    let taskList = '';

    for (let year of arrUniqYear) {

        console.log(year);

        for (let month of arrUniqMonth) {

          let displayMonth = false;

          for (let obj of arrSortedTasks) {     

            if (obj.year === year && obj.month === month) {

                taskList = taskList + obj.task;

                displayMonth = true;

            } 

          }

          if (displayMonth) {

             console.log("  " + month);

          }

          if (taskList.length > 0) {

             console.log("    " + taskList);

          }

          taskList = '';

        }
    }
```

How can we display the components in react-native with native-base? SO here don't let me post if too many code sigh. I tried a few ways buy got errors and can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I end up using array as a return object in rendering

```
  renderBillsSection() {

    const { bills } = this.props;

    if(bills || bills.length > 0 ) {

      let arrSortedTasks = _.orderBy(tasks, ['year', 'month'],['asc']);
      let arrUniqYear = _.uniqBy(arrSortedTasks, 'year');
      let arrUniqMonth = _.uniqBy(arrSortedTasks, 'month');
      let billList = '', arr = [], yearIndex = 0, monthIndex = 0, billIndex = 0;

      arrUniqYear = _.map(arrUniqYear, 'year');
      arrUniqMonth = _.map(arrUniqMonth, 'month');

      for (let year of arrUniqYear) {

          arr.push(<Text key="{yearIndex}">{year}</Text>)

          yearIndex++

          for (let month of arrUniqMonth) {

            let displayMonth = false;

            for (let obj of arrSortedTasks) {     

              if (obj.year === year && obj.month === month) {

                billList = billList + obj.task

                displayMonth = true

              } 

            }

            if (displayMonth) {

               arr.push(<Text key="{monthIndex}" style={{marginLeft:10}}>{month}</Text>)

               monthIndex++

            }

            if (billList.length > 0) {

               arr.push(<Text key="{taskIndex}" style={{marginLeft:20}}>{billList}</Text>)

               billIndex++

            }

            billList = '';            

          }


      }

      return arr;

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure about how you are planning to render it in UI, but if you want to have the data structure like this, you need to group it (and sort by monhts if its not already sorted)

`_(bills).groupBy('year').map((v,k)=> ({year: k, docs: _.sortBy(v,'month')})).value()`

it will give you another array where you have year, abd docs as nested array holding all the documents of that year, so that you can agaib have another repeat on that.

```js
const bills = [
  {year:2021, month:5, bill:'bill in 2021 may'},
  {year:2018, month:1, bill:'bill in 2018 jan'},
  {year:2019, month:1, bill:'bill in 2019 jan'},
  {year:2018, month:2, bill:'bill in 2018 feb'},
  {year:2019, month:10,bill:'bill in 2019 oct'},
  {year:2019, month:2, bill:'bill in 2019 feb'},
  {year:2019, month:6, bill:'bill in 2019 jun'},
  {year:2020, month:11,bill:'bill in 2020 nov'}
]
let groupedDoc = _(bills).groupBy('year').map((v,year)=> ({year, docs: _.sortBy(v,'month')})).value();
console.log(groupedDoc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

Here is a working snippet:

Answer (score -1):

I think you should do :

`const gropuByYear = _.groupBy(bills,'year');
console.log(_.map(groupByYear, groups => 
groups.forEach(group=>(<View> {obj.bill}</View>)))`
even you can orderBy year desc first then do the loop good luck

Comment: need to display the month too
Year is like the array of header, months is also array of subheader under each year and bill is like a list of content under each month

Answer (score -1):

You need to take a look at [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html) of React Native.

Checkout [this example](https://medium.com/@jsoendermann/sectionlist-and-getitemlayout-2293b0b916fb) and [cuiyueshuai](https://github.com/cuiyueshuai/react-native-expandable-section-flatlist) for more practical example.

SectionList Demo:

```
 <SectionList 
  renderItem={({ item, index, section }) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>} 
  renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{title}</Text>} 
  sections={[ 
   { title: 'Title1', data: ['item1', 'item2'] }, 
   { title: 'Title2', data: ['item3', 'item4'] }, 
   { title: 'Title3', data: ['item5', 'item6'] }, 
   ]} 
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index} />
```

Comment: SectionList is not suitable for handling the simple data structure of mine

Comment: Section is way to implement what you want to display. You need to create your array as per section needed. You can use for to display your data as well. But looping is not a good option to do.